# How to programmatically create a product display(node) with reference to the product?

Tags: commerce

I want to programmatically create a product display, product and link them.

How can I do it?

Comment: Hi Nikil - although I know you mean well, please refrain from adding 7 tags to all questions.  The tag wiki states "Version tags should be used only when strictly necessary" - and for questions such as this where it can ONLY be Drupal 7, there is no need for the tags.

Comment: @Chapabu i will take care of that in future. I thought there will be changes in `Contrib` modules hooks according to Drupal core version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this function in a custom module

```
function commerce_display_product_create_method($product){
    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->type = 'product_display';
    node_object_prepare($node);

    $node->title    = $product->title;
    $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

    $node->field_product['und'][0]['product_id'] = $product->product_id;
    node_save($node);
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of calling the function?

Comment: @Nikita Try it with `hook_node_insert` or just call form a function with Prepared `$product`

Comment: @Nikita if it helps you consider choosing the correct answer by clicking the tick icon on the left of any answer.